# NSFileHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify does not work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotifications

Hi I'm using NSFileHandle's readInBackgroundAndNotify method to get notifications when a log file has been updated.

I have the following code:

```
- (void)startReading
{
    NSString *logPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Logs/MyTestApp.log"];
    NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:logPath];
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(getData:)
                               name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification
                             object:fh];
    [fh readInBackgroundAndNotify];
}

- (void) getData: (NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     NSLog(@"notification received");
}
```

However the selector is never called and the notification is not received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add an NSLog to `startReading` to make sure that's getting called.
2. Log `fh`. My guess is that it's `nil` (most probably because you haven't created MyTestApp.log yet).

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) startReading is indeed being called. I NSLogged the fileHandle and this is what it returns:

<NSConcreteFileHandle: 0x20031c2a0>

Comment: Solved my problem. A sheet window was blocking the run loop.